# React Reveal showing error `componentWillReceiveProps` has been renamed

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npm-package

I got an error message when I try to use [`react-reveal`](https://github.com/rnosov/react-reveal) what's the problem or is there any other package better than it?

> Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html for details.
>
> - Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
> - If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html
> - Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.
>
> Please update the following components: `RevealBase`

[image: Warning]

I have tried the following:

```
npm i react-reveal --legacy-peer-deps
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

But nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a warning from React itself and not an error, it has nothing to do with how you install it with `npm`. What it means is the property `componentWillReceiveProps` from React is deprecated and could remove in the future React version.

However, this project `react-reveal` seems to be abandoned so there will not be any updates to fix this, more info can be found in their Github repo issue: https://github.com/rnosov/react-reveal/issues/105